# How can i get all auto GET requests made in an html page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

**so what im trying to achieve here is get a list of  http requests that are auto Made inside a requested url.**

for example lets say my code is this :

```
import requests as r
main_r = r.get('www.example.com')
```

so normaly when we are using the browser , we send a get request to www.example.com , there are some requests that are made , eitehr api .. static files ... imgs ..etc

our code does not achieve that ofc , it only make a single request and gives u the response since its not a browser .

**How could i possibly achieve that ?**

Comment: I think requests can handle simple redirects, but for api calls via ajax and whatnot, you'll need to recreate each requests in python

Comment: @SuperStew in my case , i want the generated video link  from an Encrypted AES data  , 
which can be found in another request automatically made when visiting the page .

i wish i can just make the request myself but i couldnt break the AES encrypted data , so yeah all i have left is that idea , hopefully there will be a way around that ..

Comment: maybe a driver like .. selenium or so .. can do that ?

Comment: selenium is just a remote control for your browser, so that's probably your best bet